# Office files stored on SharePoint 2010 do not open in client office application

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have an isolated issue with a user who has IE 11, office 2013 and is trying to open office files stored on SharePoint 2010 document libraries.

When he clicks on the document, the office application starts but does not open the document. He has to download a copy of the document and make changes locally.

Other users can open the files fine and their client instance of the office application works no problem to open the document. This behaviour is the same for any office file on the SharePoint 2010 farm. pdf files behave normally and open in acrobat. With text files notepad doesn't even appear so slightly different but still incorrect behaviour.

I have tried adding the site to his trusted sites in IE. Using Firefox and the behaviour is the same. Repaired office, same issue. All other users are OK.

Any help appreciated as I have exhausted google.

Comment: I know you mentioned that the site is added to his trusted sites, but have you verified that his browser is in compatibility view when he views the site? SharePoint 2010 needs Internet Explorer to emulate IE8 in order for all the integration features (which are ActiveX controls) to work.

Comment: I can try suggesting that to him, but I have had no other reports of this issue across the company. Indeed I myself can access with IE11 no issues, without needing to turn compatibility view on or use trusted sites. I will respond with the results of trying this. Thanks.

Comment: OK I tried removing compatibility view for the site on my copy of IE11 and found that the page still rendered correctly and I was able to open Office documents without issue. I can't see Compatibility View being the culprit here. In addition the site is on our intranet.

Comment: Did you try opening up the F12 developer tools and explicitly changing the browser mode from IE8 to Edge? That's the only way to be sure you're not in compatibility view. There are two main ways to trigger IE to display a site in compatibility view, including explicitly in the compatibility view settings and implicitly via the "Display intranet sites in compatibility view" checkbox. In the latter case, the site needs to be added to the "local intranet" sites list in Internet options -> Security. A site can also have a meta header tag requesting a browser to emulate a specific version.

Comment: Have you also verified that he is not using the 64-bit version of Internet Explorer?

Comment: I tried switching to Edge using Developer tools and the behaviour when I try and open an office document is not the same as the user's. In addition I am using 64-bit IE with no issues on the SharePoint 2010 site...